# PHAsset mediaSubtype value is 524288, what is the possible media types for this value?

Tags: swift, ios13, phasset

I am getting PHAsset mediaSubtype rawvalue as 524288 in ios13. what could be the media types for this value?. According to apple definition PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoTimelapse = (1UL << 18) which is 262144.

Answer (score 0):

That is screen recording video mediaSubtype.